# Android - Struggling with SQL Query

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, sqlite

In SQL Server ,I've one database and the tables in it .In Android, I've created the local SQLite Tables with same name of the tables in SQL Server and the values are also same .

I'm using the following query to view the values of some tables.

```
Select Distinct w.WorkFlowID,w.WorkFlowName ,wv.WorkFlowValueID,wv.WorkFlowValueName,'work'as prodvalue,
case when wl.StartTime IS NOT NULL then 'true' else 'false' end
 from WorkFlow w left join WorkFlowValue wv on w.WorkFlowID = wv.WorkFlowID 
left join WorkflowLog wl on w.WorkFlowID=wl.WorkFlowID and wl.WorkFlowTransId='1' 
where w.productID='47' and (wv.WorkFlowTransId='1' or wv.WorkflowTransId is null ) and 
(w.IsDeleted=0 or w.IsDeleted is null)
UNION  
Select Distinct an.AttributeID,an.AttributeName,av.AttributeValueID,isnull(av.AttributeValueName,''),'attr' as prodvalue,'false' from Attribute an left join AttributeValue av on an.AttributeID=av.AttributeID
where an.productID='47' and (av.WorkFlowTransId is null or av.WorkFlowTransId='1') and  (an.IsDeleted='false' or an.IsDeleted is null)  order by prodvalue asc
```

I want to use this  query in Android , but some functions like `isnull` is not recognizing in android . I want to make this query working in android . Please anybody help me out .

Answer (score 1):

For `ISNULL()`, use either `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`.